# Inductive defintion for real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, induction

I was learning about inductive definitions and an example was given for the natural numbers :

\[  0 \in N \wedge n \in N\implies n+1 \in N  \] 


I found a definition for all integers and all rational numbers (please correct me if I'm wrong) :

\[  0 \in Z \wedge n \in Z\implies n+1 \in Z \wedge n-1 \in Z  \] 
\[ and\]
\[ 0 \in Q \wedge n \in Q \implies n+1\in Q \wedge n-1 \in Q \wedge n \ne 0 \implies \forall x \in Q : \dfrac{x}{n} \in Q \]


I could however not come up with any inductive definition for all real numbers or all imaginary numbers. Does anyone have knowledge of such inductive definition? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a serious "size" issue here: $\mathbb{R}$ (and related structures like $\mathbb{C}$) is **uncountable**, and so there is no way to inductively generate it using a "small" starting set and a "small" number of inductive clauses.

Instead, we need to bring second-order logic - that is, quantification over sets - into the picture in a serious way. *(Technically an inductive definition is already somewhat second-order, but its second-order-ness is "tamer.")* One way to do this is to first use an inductive definition to build a "scaffold," and then describe how $\mathbb{R}$ "covers" that scaffold. For instance:

> We can build $\mathbb{Q}$ according to an inductive procedure, and then define $\mathbb{R}$ via **Dedekind cuts**.

Another option is to discard any semblance of induction and go for a "top-down" definition:

> Up to unique isomorphism, there is **exactly one** ordered field with the least upper bound property. We call any such field $\mathbb{R}$ (since any two examples are uniquely isomorphic, there isn't a serious issue here re: non-uniqueness of referent).

But ultimately, there's no way around this: defining $\mathbb{R}$ will necessarily take more work than defining $\mathbb{N}$. (See also [this earlier thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761716/is-there-an-algebraic-way-to-construct-the-reals/3761759#3761759) treating a closely-related question.)